# Bootstrap are not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use twitter bootstrap for node.js UI,The following HTML is what I got after I use Jade
what I want is to use the the jumbotroon http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/ and to put the tabs 1&2 in in the same row of the project name on the nav-bar and use the black color like in the link,I've tried many things,what Im doing wrong here ?

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse"></button>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/#">
                        Node Rec
    </a>
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="/recipes/b1">

                                    Tab1

                                </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/recipes/b1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="container"></div>
      <div class="jumbotron"></div>
      <h1>

                            List Arrivals

                        </h1>
      <ul>
        <li>

          33: LAX-Tue Dec 02 2014 16:04:41

        </li>
        <li>

          13: MKE-Tue Dec 02 2014 16:05:48
        </li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is how it look like now...

[image]

when I change it to navbar-inverse I got the opposite which is not the way the jumbotron look 
[image]

Comment: I think it might be a typo, you use the classname `navbar-defult` instead of `navbar-default`.

Comment: @ckuijjer-thanks I've changed it and still noting was changed in the UI,please see the screen shot which I've added to the post

Comment: I suggest editing the question and making a list of the things that are wrong and what you expect them to be. To make the navbar black, add the class `navbar-inverse` btw

Comment: @ckuijjer-i've changed it and now I got the opposite colors,see the post with the new pic,what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: All your content is a child of the `<nav>`. You should only have the navbar's content in there.

Comment: @ckuijjer-since I new to this,can you please provide example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a start. I've moved the jumbotron outside the `<nav>`.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse"></button>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/#">
                        Node Rec
    </a>
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="/recipes/b1">Tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/recipes/b1">Tab2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>

                            List Arrivals

                        </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>

        33: LAX-Tue Dec 02 2014 16:04:41

      </li>
      <li>

        13: MKE-Tue Dec 02 2014 16:05:48
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot voted up!Btw do you know Jade ?I think that the problem is with Indenting but not able to find what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are welcome! I don't know jade, but in these cases its best to take a look at the output directly. Sounds indeed like an issue in your templates